# ReplaceLayer: Incorrect argument or missing argument in call

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

i am trying to replace a layer in my layergraph-object, using matlab.

I am using the command "replaceLayer(lgraph,name,layer)" , which is documented in the following URL:

https://de.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/layergraph.replacelayer.html

The explicit line is:

```
lgraph = replaceLayer(lgraph,name,layer);
```

Where lgraph is:

```
  DAGNetwork with properties:

     Layers: [144×1 nnet.cnn.layer.Layer]
Connections: [170×2 table]
 InputNames: {'data'}
OutputNames: {'classoutput'}
```

the name is 'fc' (for fully connected)

and the layer itself with the following attributes:

```
layer = 

  FullyConnectedLayer with properties:

          Name: 'fc'

   Hyperparameters
     InputSize: 720
    OutputSize: 8

   Learnable Parameters
       Weights: [8×720 double]
          Bias: [8×1 double]
```

I already tried to replace the old fully connected layer with a new fully connected layer which has the same number of outputs, because i thought those numbers need to be the same. But it still throws the exact same error message.

```
Check for incorrect argument data type or missing argument in call to function 'replaceLayer'.
```

Now i don't know what to try next.

Things i already tried:

1. Using a default weight-initialization so that the weight-attributes of the new layer are non-empty
2. Using the same number of outputs for the old (to be replaced) and the new (inserted) fully-connected layer.

Would be cool if someone could help me, i did not find anything useful in the matlab-forums. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, i need to add the following line before:

```
lgraph=layerGraph(lgraph);
```